# Cordova notification alert not working on device ready or load but working onClick events

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am new with `cordova` app development and trying to show an alert message when app loads but currently confused why the `cordova-plugin-dialogs` does NOT fire on load but when I used onclick event it fires.

Here is my code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <button onclick="checkPolicyConfirm()">Click Me</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script>

 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function alertRegiterDismissedNow() {}

        function checkPolicyConfirm() {
            navigator.notification.alert(
                "Setting is not available as of now", // message
                alertRegiterDismissedNow, // callback
                "Test Notifications", // title
                "OK" // buttonName
            );
        }




        function onDeviceReady() {

            checkPolicyConfirm();
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```